# Working example of suppressing failures when accessibility testing in Android Espresso?

Tags: android-espresso, accessibility

I have my test setup like this:

Base class:

```
public class AccessibilityBase {

    public static AccessibilityValidator accessibilityValidator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void enableAccessibilityChecks() {
        accessibilityValidator = AccessibilityChecks.enable();
        accessibilityValidator.setThrowExceptionForErrors(true);
    }
    ...
```

Test class:

```
public class LoginAccessibilityTest extends AccessibilityBase {

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<LoginActivity> activityTestRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(LoginActivity.class, true, false);

    private static Matcher<? super AccessibilityViewCheckResult> suppress = Matchers.anyOf(
            allOf(matchesCheckNames(is("TouchTargetSizeViewCheck")),
                    matchesViews(withId(R.id.main_button_login)))
    );

    @BeforeClass
    public static void enableAccessibilityChecks() {
        accessibilityValidator = AccessibilityChecks.enable();
        accessibilityValidator.setSuppressingResultMatcher(suppress);
    }

    @Test
    public void testLoginActivity() {
        Context context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, LoginActivity.class);
        LoginActivity loginActivity = activityTestRule.launchActivity(intent);

        // UPDATE: Had to pass suppress through here to the base class
        runAllTests(loginActivity, suppress);
    }
}
```

And yet, when I run this it still fails with this error message:

java.lang.AssertionError: Button app:id/main_button_login: View falls below the minimum recommended size for touch targets. Minimum touch target size is 48x48dp. Actual size is 446.0x45.0dp (screen density is 3.0).

UPDATE: The key was in my runAllTests method. I've fixed it by passing the suppress matcher in the test class to runAllTests()

```
private static void runTests(Activity activity, Set<AccessibilityViewHierarchyCheck> checks, Matcher<? super AccessibilityViewCheckResult> suppress) {
        List<AccessibilityViewCheckResult> results = new LinkedList<>();
        View rootView = activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content);
        for (AccessibilityViewHierarchyCheck check : checks) {
            try {
                results.addAll(check.runCheckOnViewHierarchy(rootView));
            } catch (Exception ex) {

            }
        }
        if (suppress != null) {
            AccessibilityCheckResultUtils.suppressMatchingResults(results, suppress);
        }
```

That last bit was necessary even though I had it set in the test's @BeforeClass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers depending on which libraries are being used. As a note, the first example here is deprecated, but works fine:

```
import com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework.AccessibilityViewCheckResult // <-- deprecated
    ...
    companion object {
        @BeforeClass
        @JvmStatic
        fun enableAccessibilityChecks() {
            val suppress: Matcher<AccessibilityViewCheckResult> = anyOf(
            allOf(matchesCheckNames(`is`("TouchTargetSizeViewCheck")),
                    matchesViews(withId(R.id.small_button))),
            allOf(matchesCheckNames(`is`("DuplicateClickableBoundsViewCheck")),
                    matchesViews(withId(R.id.overlap_button)))
            )
            AccessibilityChecks.enable()
                .setRunChecksFromRootView(true)
                .setSuppressingResultMatcher(suppress)
        }
    }
```

And the newer version:

```
import androidx.test.espresso.accessibility.AccessibilityChecks
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.withId
import com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework.AccessibilityCheckResultUtils.matchesCheckNames
import com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accessibility.framework.AccessibilityCheckResultUtils.matchesViews
import org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.*

...

    init {
        AccessibilityChecks.enable()
            .setRunChecksFromRootView(true)
            .apply {
                setSuppressingResultMatcher(
                    anyOf(
                        allOf(matchesCheckNames(`is`("TouchTargetSizeViewCheck")),
                            matchesViews(withId(R.id.small_button))),
                        allOf(matchesCheckNames(`is`("DuplicateClickableBoundsViewCheck")),
                            matchesViews(withId(R.id.overlap_button)))
                    )
                )
            }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

**you should never suppress a failure.**

It is there to tell you what to correct.

The minimum size is not the overall size, it is the minimum in each direction (so you could have a `1000dp` wide button that is `45dp` high and you would still fail as the height is not a minimum of `48dp`)

I know it may seem that `3dp` is nothing, but really they are minimums and you should try to exceed them.

Imagine that you have Parkinson's Disease or Cerebral Palsy, you would not have the accuracy to hit small hit targets and that is why the minimums are in place.

Make your button just that little bit bigger instead of trying to remove the error (`3dp` can't possibly ruin a design).

Every single one of your customers will thank you for doing this. (Imagine someone as a passenger in a car trying to hit your button, same principle on accuracy.)

Comment: I need to suppress the failures at the start so I can get everything first set up for a11y automated testing, then flag each issue so we can address them. If they aren't flagged with a suppression, then no one knows what is wrong on each activity until the test has been ran, where a line of code suppressing the issue is immediate and highly visible.

Comment: "There can be cases when an accessibility issue is known but has not been resolved. With the help of AccessibilityValidator implemented in com.google.android.apps.common.testing.accesibility.framework, you can suppress it:"

https://books.google.com/books?id=fhKLDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA160&lpg=PA160&dq=espresso+AccessibilityValidator&source=bl&ots=PiyueIM12u&sig=ACfU3U2xBv8r5XVPKDnk5xucjxDReRsEAg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwit3c7asuzlAhWETN8KHY9FAWgQ6AEwBnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q&f=false